# XSLT Transformer VS Debugger

Tags: xml, debugging, xslt

I would like to create a VS project that I can use as a debugger tool for xslt code. I have loaded the xml schema as well as the xslt file. using the XslTransform class I can call XslTransform.Transform passing in the xml but I am not able to hit the break point I have added to the xslt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you need to use `XslCompiledTransform`, not `XslTransform`. And you need to use the `new XslCompiledTransform(true)` constructor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163418(v=vs.110).aspx, additionally the following conditions

- The style sheet is passed to the Load method either as a URI, or an implementation of the XmlReader class that implements the IXmlLineInfo interface. The IXmlLineInfo interface is implemented on all text-parsing XmlReader objects.
- In other words, if the style sheet is loaded using an IXPathNavigable object, such as an XmlDocument or XPathDocument, or an XmlReader implementation that does not implement the IXmlLineInfo interface, you cannot debug the style sheet.
- The XmlResolver used to load the style sheet is a file-based XmlResolver, such as the XmlUrlResolver (this is the default XmlResolver used by the XslCompiledTransform class).
- The style sheet is located on the local machine or on the intranet.

need to be true.

Comment: When I used the XslCompiledTransform this is the error returned Token Text in state Start would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment.

Comment: I think a particular debugging problem is better described with code in a separate question. The error sounds as if you somewhere create a document fragment where the code expects a well-formed document with a single root element. Whether you want to fix that in XSLT or at the C# API level I don't know, I think you should provide the details of what you have in a new question.